# how to use sshpass in shell script to check whether directory exists or not?

Tags: shell, sshpass

I have a shell script, it basically run in one environment, and it needs to check whether directory exists on another environment or not.

I tried in below two ways but no luck.

Way 1 :

```
if [ -d "sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh root@192.168.16.01 /home/test" ]; then
echo "YES"
fi
```

Way 2 :

```
if [sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh root@192.168.16.01 '[ -d /home/test ]']; then
echo "YES"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets in `if` tests are not part of the `if` syntax. The `[` is a command of its own (also called `test`).

The syntax of an `if` statement is roughly <sup>(see [Shell Grammar Rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02) for more if you are *really* curious)</sup>:

```
if <command that returns true or false>; then
    <other commands>
fi
```

Your first attempt is just incorrect because `-d` takes a directory name not a string which is a command you want to run.

The second attempt is close you just have too many square brackets (and not enough spaces for those square brackets).

Remove the outer square brackets from the second attempt and it will work (assuming `sshpass` properly handles returning the return value of the `ssh` command):

```
if sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh root@192.168.16.01 '[ -d /home/test ]'; then
    echo "YES"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`sshpass` is scarcely used.

Maybe the same as with `ssh`use batch mode works

```
sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o BatchMode=yes root@192.168.16.01 "if [ -d /home/test ] ; then echo Y ; fi" > a.out
```

You will then collect the result in `a.out`